# Exact Target Charset

Tags: marketing-cloud, php, encoding

I send Data via SOAP to Exact Target extension. 
Everything work fine, but if I send some characters from another languages I have problems.

I have tried to set line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` to WSLD ExactTargetWSDL but it didn't help.
Here are part of script:

```
$myclient = new ET_Client();
$extensionTableName = "table_name";
$postDRRow = new ET_DataExtension_Row();
$postDRRow->authStub = $myclient;
$postDRRow->Name = $extensionTableName;
foreach($rulesDataToSend as $ruleData) {
     $postDRRow->props = $ruleData;//here I set data. If I string in English, everything is ok. But if Spain or Russian, there will be wrong symbols         
     $postDRRow->post();
 }
```

As example:

```
$postDRRow->props = array("Name" =>"SomeNameInEnglish");//Display In Exact Target Extension Table Fine
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any code here that has foreign languages. That may help someone when trying to solve your question.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I think we still need  a bit more info.  Do you have some sample strings that you pass in? Is the issue when you display them in an email, or is the issue in the data extension?

Comment: Here I can not save comment or answer with Russian characters

Comment: Here google link with russian word in search input https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=rgfergfer&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SOAP, I was able to pass in the values properly, and they displayed in the data extension with no problem.

Here is a [gist with the code](https://gist.github.com/kellyjandrews/11252111)

And a screen shot of the data extension.

[image]

I would verify what is happening in your SOAP packet by logging your requests, and making sure the characters are correct there.  Another debugging tip would be to test the SOAP packets using SOAP UI - [here is a tutorial to get going with that](http://kellyjandrews.com/soap-testing-with-soap-ui/). This will verify that your account can handle what you are passing in, and narrow down your issue to the PHP code somewhere.

Hope this helps!